# Can't seem to throw, handle the exception while parsing input into different types (java)

Tags: java, swing

The focus is in actionPerformed method close to the end. In that method I'm responding to a listener with a statement. I tried to throw and handle an exception which was NumberFormatException that came up when I put in a number rather than a Binary. I'm guessing I have to break the parsings into small bits and put them in try-catch blocks there but I'm not experience enough to get the picture going.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class BaseConverter extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private JTextField txtNum1;
    private JTextField txtNum2;
    private JButton btnConvert;
    private JButton btnClear;

public BaseConverter()
{
    this("Base Converter");
}
public BaseConverter(String title)
{
    super(title);
    Container canvas = this.getContentPane();

    canvas.add(createCenterPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    canvas.add(createSouthPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    this.setSize(400, 150);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setLocation(100, 100);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

}
private JPanel createCenterPanel() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,2));
    panel.add(new JLabel("In Base 2: "));
    txtNum1 = new JTextField(16);
    panel.add(wrapMeInAPanel(txtNum1));

    panel.add(new JLabel("In Base 10: "));
    txtNum2 = new JTextField(16);
    panel.add(wrapMeInAPanel(txtNum2));

    panel.add(new JLabel("Clear boxes first!"));
    return panel;
}
private JPanel createSouthPanel()
{
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    panel.add( btnConvert = new JButton("CONVERT"));
    btnConvert.setToolTipText("Remember to clear your boxes first!");
    btnConvert.addActionListener(this);
    panel.add( btnClear = new JButton("CLEAR"));
    btnClear.addActionListener(this);

    return panel;
}
private JPanel wrapMeInAPanel(Component c)
{ 
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(c);
    return panel;
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    if(e.getSource() == btnConvert && txtNum2.getText().equals(""))
    {

        try {
            txtNum2.setText((String.valueOf((Integer.valueOf(txtNum1.getText(),2)))));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1.getMessage());
        }


    }

    if(e.getSource() == btnConvert && txtNum1.getText().equals("") )
    {
        txtNum1.setText(Integer.toBinaryString((Integer.valueOf(Integer.parseInt((txtNum2.getText()))))));
    }

    if(e.getSource() == btnClear)
    {
        txtNum1.setText(null);
        txtNum2.setText(null);
    }
}

//  public static boolean isBinary(int number)  
//    {
//      int copyOfInput = number;
//      
//      while (copyOfInput != 0) {
//          if (copyOfInput % 10 > 1) {
//              return false;
//          }
//          copyOfInput = copyOfInput / 10;
//      }
//      return true;
//  }

}
```

Comment: Okay, but what's your question?

Comment: When I run the program, it returns a NumberFormatException when I put in a number rather than a Binary, so I need help finding out ways to fix that. Other than that, I'm not sure which parsing caused the program to blow up.

Comment: The stack trace will tell where in your code the problem occured

Comment: Here is what I got inputting "12" as Base 2 number.

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "12"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Unknown Source)
 at BaseConverter.actionPerformed(BaseConverter.java:74)

Comment: Fair enough, "12" is not a valid number in Base 2 - Base 2 is binary.

Comment: I wasn't able to catch that Exception and I'm not sure if I have to put nested try-catch blocks to break the parsing statement down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap the conversion of the decimal value to binary in a `try-catch` block as well, for example

```
try {
    txtNum1.setText(Integer.toBinaryString((Integer.valueOf(Integer.parseInt((txtNum2.getText()))))));
} catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1.getMessage());
}
```

You may also want to use `String#trim#isEmpty` to test for blank `String` values

## Runnable example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class BaseConverter extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                BaseConverter frame = new BaseConverter("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private JTextField txtNum1;
    private JTextField txtNum2;
    private JButton btnConvert;
    private JButton btnClear;

    public BaseConverter() {
        this("Base Converter");
    }

    public BaseConverter(String title) {
        super(title);
        Container canvas = this.getContentPane();

        canvas.add(createCenterPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        canvas.add(createSouthPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        this.setSize(400, 150);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setLocation(100, 100);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    private JPanel createCenterPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 2));
        panel.add(new JLabel("In Base 2: "));
        txtNum1 = new JTextField(16);
        panel.add(wrapMeInAPanel(txtNum1));

        panel.add(new JLabel("In Base 10: "));
        txtNum2 = new JTextField(16);
        panel.add(wrapMeInAPanel(txtNum2));

        panel.add(new JLabel("Clear boxes first!"));
        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createSouthPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        panel.add(btnConvert = new JButton("CONVERT"));
        btnConvert.setToolTipText("Remember to clear your boxes first!");
        btnConvert.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(btnClear = new JButton("CLEAR"));
        btnClear.addActionListener(this);

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel wrapMeInAPanel(Component c) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(c);
        return panel;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == btnConvert && txtNum2.getText().equals("")) {
            try {
                txtNum2.setText((String.valueOf((Integer.valueOf(txtNum1.getText(), 2)))));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1.getMessage());
            }
        } else if (e.getSource() == btnConvert && txtNum1.getText().equals("")) {
            try {
                txtNum1.setText(Integer.toBinaryString((Integer.valueOf(Integer.parseInt((txtNum2.getText()))))));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1.getMessage());
            }

        } else if (e.getSource() == btnClear) {
            txtNum1.setText(null);
            txtNum2.setText(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ah, that's another value that could potentially blow up the program. I put the coversion you mentioned in a try-catch block, but the error is still the same. Could it be because of ---  Integer.valueOf(txtNum1.getText(),2) --- ?

Comment: I just get the `JOptionPane` popping up.  The `try-catch`, the way it's demonstrated above, is meant to catch any `NumberFormatException`s which might be thrown by the code between the `try` and the `catch`...

Comment: hmm, the pop-up didn't show on my computer, is there a way that you could show me a screenshot of yours having the JOptionPane popping up?

Comment: Wow, incredible, I don't know why mine doesn't show like that.

Comment: Make sure you clean and build the project.  You might consider placing `System.out.println` statements in to see where the code is running or debug it...

Comment: D: I have another copy of the exact same program, it's just in a different folder of a Java project, I used the try-catch block on that converting statement and it works!

Comment: mind blown, I have no clue why it works now... I copy and pasted mine over your example (which i overwritten mine befofe that to try and run) to test mine and it works... D: